# Separate values into multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

| ID | Contact No | Ext | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 75865558 | 123 | work |
| 0001 | 207586558 | NULL | home |
| 0001 | 207586559 | NULL | cell |
| 0001 | 746655558 | 321 | work |
| 0002 | 946655558 | 323 | work |
| 0002 | 2356841 | NULL | home |
| 0003 | 6655558 | NULL | cell |

**I want to split the table up into**

| ID | HPhone | CPhone1 | CPhone2 | WPhone1 | Ext1 | WPhone2 | Ext2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 207586558 | 207586559 | NULL | 75865558 | 123 | 746655558 | 321 |
| 0002 | 2356841 | NULL | NULL | 946655558 | 323 | NULL | NULL |
| 0003 | NULL | 6655558 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

Any id can at most have 1 HPhone, 2CPhones, and 2 WPhones/Ext. The GUI only has fields for 2 work phones and 2 cell phone; however, in the table cell1 and cell2 both have the type of 'cell' and same for work1 and work2.

I'm new to databases so I'm not specifically looking to be given the answer but any advise about how I can split the first table into something similar to the second table would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a `PIVOT`, but those quickly become messy when you're pivoting multiple things conditionally. So I would use `MAX/CASE` aggregates, like this (the CTE is used to give a deterministic order for numbers of the same type; if you want to change that, just change the `ORDER BY` inside the `OVER()` clause):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY ID, [Type] ORDER BY [Contact No])
  FROM dbo.SourceTable
)
SELECT ID, 
  HPhone  = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'home' THEN [Contact No] END),
  CPhone1 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'cell' AND rn = 1 THEN [Contact No] END),
  CPhone2 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'cell' AND rn = 2 THEN [Contact No] END),
  WPhone1 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 1 THEN [Contact No] END),
  Ext1    = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 1 THEN [Ext] END),
  WPhone2 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 2 THEN [Contact No] END),
  Ext2    = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 2 THEN [Ext] END)
FROM x
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```