# please explain the query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

This looks like what I need as well. However, not being proficient in query making sense out of some of this.. so can you please clarify some things for me?

```
;WITH x AS <--- is this a comment?
( SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [Type] ORDER BY [Contact No]) FROM dbo.SourceTable )
SELECT ID, HPhone = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'home' THEN [Contact No] END),
CPhone1 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'cell' AND rn = 1 THEN [Contact No] END),
 CPhone2 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'cell' AND rn = 2 THEN [Contact No] END),
 WPhone1 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 1 THEN [Contact No] END)
, Ext1 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 1 THEN [Ext] END),
 WPhone2 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 2 THEN [Contact No] END),
 Ext2 = MAX(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'work' AND rn = 2 THEN [Ext] END)

FROM x <---------- what is 'x'? GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID;
```

I copied the query and pasted it here from https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242195

Answer (score 5):

This is the SQL syntax for a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (CTE). It defines a "virtual table" named `x`, from which you can later select.

The semicolon that precedes `WITH` is a quirk [explained here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/why-should-a-cte-start-with-a-semi-colon).